# Making Quotation(' or ") a String Possible?

Tags: c#

im working on a code editor and i want to know if how to transfer a quotation into a string .

im using parameters something like this:

```
 if (token == "letterX" || token.StartsWith("x") || token.StartsWith("X"))
            {
                int length = line.Length - (index - start);
                string commentText = rtb.Text.Substring(index, length);
                rtb.SelectionStart = index;
                rtb.SelectionLength = length;
                lb.Visible = true;
                int i = commentText.IndexOf(token); 

            }
```

and i want to know how to replace the letter X into quotation, like what in this regex expression shows:

```
Regex singlequote = new Regex("\'[^\"]*\'");
```

output that i want to achieve was when i type singlequote and ended with another singlequote(closing), text inside quotation will change to color marroon(but i already have the code for that) . same as doublequote started with a double then closes with another1 .

i just wanna ask how to make single(') and doublequote(") a string .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are going to have `"` in a string, your can use `\`.

```
token.StartsWith("\"");
```

Comment: @user2234790 you find it as the accepted answer, you can also mark it as accepted (green check appears bellow the up votes)

Comment: @user2234790 glad to be helpful.