# How to make /* and */ a string?

Tags: c#

related to this topic: [Making Quotation(' or ") a String Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161293/making-quotation-or-a-string-possible)

my question is how to make `/*` and `*/` string inside this code:

```
    if (token == "commentOpen&Close" || token.StartsWith("/*") & token.EndsWith("*/"))
    {
        int length = line.Length - (index - start);
        string commentText = rtb.Text.Substring(index, length);
        rtb.SelectionStart = index;
        rtb.SelectionLength = length;
        int i = commentText.IndexOf(token);

        HighlighType.commentsType(rtb);
    }
```

the `token.StartsWith(" ")` and `token.EndsWith(" ")` what should i input inside?

and in additional how to make the text inside /* and */ function all with highlighting function even not in a row line .

somewhere within this code i guess:

```
int length = line.Length - (index - start);
            string commentText = rtb.Text.Substring(index, length);
```

---

the one that answers:

```
if (token == "commentOpen&Close" || token.StartsWith(@"/*") & token.EndsWith(@"*/"))
```

work fine but i guess HE deleted it ^^.but i still need a help for 2nd question if its ok . on how to make text inside /* and */ all with highligting even not in a row line .

Comment: What's the problem exactly? `Console.WriteLine("/*");` and `Console.WriteLine("*/");` show those two strings parse just fine.

Comment: Yep. I don't see the problem too, I just tried your exact line with no problems in VS2010

Answer (score 3):

Change the bitwise `&` operator to a `&&` or `||` operator on that line. Also add brackets:

```
if (token == "commentOpen&Close" || (token.StartsWith("/*") && token.EndsWith("*/")))
```